# How to efficiently preserve a really big navigation history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

When I was using Mac, my Firefox stored items in its history for really long times. Sometimes I needed to find a link to a site I have seen two years ago and it found it! Also, the autocomplete in the Firefox bar is really great, so a long history and the autocompleting yield a wonderful feature to me.

Unfortunately, it seems this does not happen in Ubuntu's Firefox. I looked for solutions but I just got some [Firefox developers](http://blog.bonardo.net/2010/01/20/places-got-async-expiration) saying the option of expanding history is out for performance issues and one is well advised to not try to change it (which read to me as saying "we cannot make it work well so we limit the scope").

Anyway, my question is: is there a way of efficiently expand the size of Firefox history? Sorry for my bitterness, but a solution with strings attached (mostly say that I should not do it, like [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/?src=search)) is *not* solution for me. Does someone have the same need of mine and found a solution?

Comment: It maybe a nice idea to reconsider what you've written in the second para. First, you seem to point at Ubuntu's Firefox; then, you allow that "maybe this is not a Firefox problem in Ubuntu but a limitation of the new versions". So what is your basis for the first claim? If you don't have any, you could consider editing your question so that you just ask a question without the speculative aspect.

Comment: @vasa1 you are right. As an improvement in the question, I removed this speculative part, sine this problem was added in Firefox 4 - that is, all Firefox versions I was using had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages` to a higher number (or perhaps `-1`)? To access this, type `about:config` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I am not sure this works; a cursory search of the entries exposed by `about:config` revealed this to me. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can edit this post to improve it (or post their own answer).